# PDO use Fetch to get the first row from a query (without using FetchAll first?)

Tags: pdo, row, fetch, fetchall

Using PHP, PDO to query my games database, to retrieve a game that is available to join. If I use Fetch it will bring back the last row that meets the criteria. I want the first row, so I'm currently using FetchAll then looking at the first row retrieved. Is there a way to use Fetch and tell it to just get the first row. As using FetchAll seems like it is gathering a lot more data than I require.

I'm very new to all of this (animator by trade), but having got my head around old mysql I've now moved over to using PDO which seems great. Slowly building a working asynchronous game server.

Here's my code, which works but I wonder if it could be more efficient, if I did'nt use FetchAll.

```
       //Set variables to use when searching for random game in table
       $player2_id = 0; //if 0 then player 2 slot has not been filled.
       $whose_turn = 2;  //if 2 then its player twos go...so good to join.


        //IS THERE A RANDOM GAME TO JOIN 
        $current_game = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM games_database WHERE player2_id=? AND whose_turn=?");
        $current_game->execute(array($player_2_id, $whose_turn));

        //Fetch All the results
        $random_game_to_use = $current_game->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Get the first of all the results
        $firstAvailableGame = $random_game_to_use[0];
        $rand_game_name = $firstAvailableGame['game_name'];
```

I hope that makes sense. Any help or pearls of wisdom would be gratefully received. Also just want to say Stackoverflow has been an incredibly helpful website in my learning of coding PHP and PDO database queries. I've probably tried to learn to code about 4 times in my life but finally its starting to stick nicely. This is my first question... thanks Jon.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM games_database WHERE player2_id=? AND whose_turn=? LIMIT 1` .Then use `fetch()`

Comment: Thanks will try LIMIT 1 this evening...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no `ORDER BY` clause in your query, the result set is unsorted by definition. It **might** have a sorting, but this is not guaranteed.

Since you obviously want the "first" and not the "last" row, you want to sort by something and therefore you should specify your desired sorting so that the database actually sorts your result set.

As soon as you have appended the `ORDER BY something` clause to your query, you can further append `ASC` or `DESC` to control the direction of the sorting and to push the liked row to the top (for example `ORDER BY something DESC`). (This makes "last row the first" or "first row the last".)

Then you can (and should) `LIMIT` your result set to one row, since you only want one row. So append `LIMIT 1` to your query, to retrieve exactly the row you want.

You can now use `fetch()` to request the first (and only) row, which is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks will try using LIMIT 1 this evening... as well as the other idea of using ORDER... really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score -1):

## Selecting only one record with fetch()

**/core/model.php**

@select values from table

@access public

@param string $table The name of the table

@param string $fieldname

@param string $id

@return the specific row as an object on success or throw PDOException on failure

@warn : Select only unique values from a column

```
public function dbSelectOne($table, $fieldname=null, $id=null)
{
$this->conn();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$fieldname`=:id";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

**Example:**

```
$client = $this->pdo->dbSelectOne('clients', 'id_client', $id );
echo $client->name;
```

**Notice: You will have to make a validation in case the record is not found.**

The *try{} catch{}* are useless for empty object, because pdo is not throwing any error.

```
if(empty($client)){ /* do something */ }
```

However, you can catch any error if the table or field names are not valid.

Comment: Please, never use a function like this

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: For too may reasons. You made this function insecure and inflexible at once. such a function should accept only two arguments - a query and array with data for execute

Comment: It is only 1 function in the core/model.

Comment: So what? It doesn't make it any better

Comment: It is only one function in the core/model.php. I use the core class Model to create a model for clients : models/client.php and load it in a controller with `$this->load->model('Client')` to use it and pass it to a view. It is flexible, the core/model has many functions. This fonction should not be called directly from a public scripts. In fact, i use `$this->pdo`for the example only. The real code in the controller is `$this->Client->dbSelectOne()`.

Comment: SQL is far more rich language than you think. If your only idea of using it is calling records by primary key, then you don't need no RDBMS at all and key-value storage is all you need

Comment: It could be optimize like this: `$this->Client->dbSelectOne($id); `

Comment: this your latter comment is irrelevant to mine